# What songs is Lucio playing?

Tags: overwatch, game-music-identification

Whether he's Crossfading between speed or healing, or using Amp It Up, there is a very audible song that is being played as he moves around.  Very noticeably, there are two songs being played: one while he is in healing mode, and the other in speed mode.

In this video you can hear some of the music, in-game it fades away after a few seconds:

I've looked in the Overwatch official OST and cannot find the songs listed anywhere. What songs is Lucio playing as he jams along?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The songs are from Lúcio's (No longer fictional) album, *[Synaesthesia Auditiva](https://youtu.be/Yc00VF9YVw0)*.

The "healing" song is "[Rejuvenescência](https://soundcloud.com/playoverwatch/rejuvenescencia)". The "movement speed" song is "[We Move Together As One](https://soundcloud.com/playoverwatch/wemovetogetherasone)".

Comment: Do you know where I can buy the album or download it?

Comment: The album doesn't really exist. The SoundCloud links above are the only place these songs are available outside the game; they were provided by Blizzard in a faux press release for the album: https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/19828053/

Comment: afaik they are on the audiotrack cd of the Collectors edition aswell.

Comment: That seems likely, but until release day we won't know for sure.

Comment: It turns out these two songs are NOT on the Collector's Edition soundtrack.

Comment: @senpai Blizzard recently released the full album as part of blizz con, I added a link to a youtube video to the full album to the answer if you want to listen. The Full version was availbe for free download at https://luciomusic.com/ but it appears to be down right now.

Answer (score 3):

No, Lúcio's ability songs are not in the official soundtrack, but you can download them on [Blizzard's Overwatch press page](http://blizzard.gamespress.com/Overwatch?focusOnFileCollectionId=Cosplay-Reference-Kits).

Scroll down until you see two WAV files. Those are what you're looking for. You might want to convert them to something more handy, like FLAC, though.